# OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input 1575262698000.0 with the unit 's'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to turn that number from a dataframe into a datetime, the colum time['date'] looks like the following:

```
0     1.575263e+12
1     1.575263e+12
2     1.575263e+12
3     1.575263e+12
4     1.575307e+12
          ...     
95    1.576521e+12
96    1.576521e+12
97    1.576521e+12
98    1.576521e+12
99    1.576521e+12
Name: date, Length: 100, dtype: float64
```

I tried the following:

```
print(pd.to_datetime(time['date'], unit='s'))
```

But I had the issue in the title, and if I try without `unit='s'` the column looks as follow:

```
0    1970-01-01 00:26:15.262698000
1    1970-01-01 00:26:15.262699000
2    1970-01-01 00:26:15.262698000
3    1970-01-01 00:26:15.262701000
4    1970-01-01 00:26:15.307111000
                  ...             
95   1970-01-01 00:26:16.521124623
96   1970-01-01 00:26:16.521116000
97   1970-01-01 00:26:16.521118000
98   1970-01-01 00:26:16.521145701
99   1970-01-01 00:26:16.521147000
Name: date, Length: 100, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Which is of course wrong, any idea why? thanks!

Here is an example of the input: `1575262698000.0` and the output should be the following: 2019-12-02 04:58:18

Comment: can you give an example input and expected output?

Comment: Yes @synaptikon, I addded an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error comes from [pandas timestamp limitations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-timestamp-limits): It looks like your input column is not in seconds but in milliseconds (ms). Taking only one value for simplification purposes:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(1575262698000, unit='ms')
Timestamp('2019-12-02 04:58:18')
```

If you want to use seconds as unit, you can do

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(1575262698000 / 1000, unit='s')
Timestamp('2019-12-02 04:58:18')
```

Removing `unit` arg yields datetimes around 1970 because default value for this parameter is `ns` ie nanoseconds. And 1575262698000 nanoseconds are around 1575 seconds or said differently around 25 minutes after 01/01/1970 !